# InputText component behaves unexpectedly

Tags: blazor

To add events and formatters to the `InputText` component of Blazor, I have created an inherited component, `InputText2`.

It looks like this:

```cshap
public class InputText2 : InputText
{
    [Parameter]
    public Action<string> OnBlur { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<string, string> Formatter { get; set; }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        var parseResult = base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result, out validationErrorMessage);

        OnBlur?.Invoke(value);

        return parseResult;
    }

    protected override string FormatValueAsString(string value)
    {
        var result = Formatter?.Invoke(value) ?? value;
        //CurrentValueAsString = result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

The Formatter parameter takes a `Func` that modifies the string in some way. In my example, I wanted postal codes in the format "12345" to be formatted "123 45". In `FormatValueAsString`, result gets the correct value, but this is not reflected in the UI after rendering. However, if I do set `CurrentValueAsString` to result, then it works. But I can't find any reason for this. And in other examples, that property is never touched either. Also, it seems to be able to create loops between `FormatValueAsString` and `TryParseValueFromString`.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

`FormatValueAsString` is just used by `InputBase` to format the `CurrentValue` in the `getter` for `CurrentValueAsString`.

The value that is bound to the input control and hence what you see on the page is the value of `CurrentValue`

So, if you want the displayed value to use the formatted value, you need to set `CurrentValue` to that formatted value - and this is what happens when you include the line to set `CurrentValueAsString = result` - the `setter` on `CurrentValueAsString` sets `CurrentValue`.